# Closing SSE connection in browser causes segfault in uWSGI when multiple sets of child processes are running concurrently

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, uwsgi, server-sent-events

I'm building a web application for processing ~60,000 (and growing) large files, perform some analysis and return a "best guess" that needs to be verified by a user. The files will be refined by category to avoid loading every file, but I'm still left with a scenario where I might have to process 1000+ files at a time.

These are large files that can take up to 8-9 seconds each to process, and in a 1000+ file situation it is impractical to have a user wait 8 seconds between reviews or 2 hours+ while the files are processed before hand.

To overcome this, I've decided to use multiprocessing to spawn several workers, each of which will pick from a queue of files, process them and insert into an output queue. I have another method that basically polls the output queue for items and then streams them to the client when one becomes available.

We're using gevent with uWSGI and Django in our environment and I'm aware that child process creation via multiprocessing in the context of gevent yields an undesired event loop state in the child. Greenlets spawned before forking are duplicated in the child. Therefore, I've decided to use [lets](https://github.com/sublee/lets) to assist in the handling of the child processes.

This all works beautifully while uninterrupted. However, if a user were to switch categories anytime while files are still being processed, I close the SSE connection in the browser and open another causing a new set of child processes to spawn and killing the existing processes (or attempting to). This causes one of two things to happen.

When I yield out the results to the client, I get an `IOError` from uWSGI because the connection has closed. I wrapped the entire function in a `try...finally` and kill all the workers before the function exits.

I can either block while the processes are killed or do it in the background. Each method has different consequences. When trying to kill without blocking, the original processes are never killed, the new processes stop yielding, and any request (from any page) to the server hangs until I manually kill all uWSGI processes.

When blocking, uWSGI reports a segmentation fault, the main worker is killed and restarted, killing all child processes - new and old.

An example of the JavaScript used to open/close the connection:

```js
var state = {};

function analyze(){
    // If a connection exists, close it.
    if (state.evtSource) {
        state.evtSource.close();
    }
    // Create a new connection to the server.
    evtSource = state.evtSource = new EventSource('?myarg=myval');
    evtSource.onmessage = function(message){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Server-side example code:

```py
from item import Item
import lets
import multiprocessing
import time

MAX_WORKERS = 10

# Worker is outside of ProcessFiles because ``lets``
# pickles the target.
def worker(item):
    return item.process()

class ProcessFiles(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.file_count = 0
        self.pool = lets.ProcessPool(MAX_WORKERS)

    def query_for_results(self):
        # Query db for records of files to process.
        # Return results and set self.file_count equal to
        # the number of records returned.
        pass

    def start(self):

        # Queue up files to process.
        for result in self.query_for_results():
            item = Item(result)
            self.input_queue.append(item)

        # Spawn up to MAX_WORKERS child processes to analyze
        # all of the items in the input queue. Append processed file
        # to output queue.
        for item in self.input_queue:
            self.pool.apply_async(worker, args=(item,), callback=self.callback)

        # Poll for items to send to client.
        return self.get_processed_items()

    def callback(self, processed):
        self.output_queue.put(processed)

    def get_processed_items(self):

        # Wait for the output queue to hold at least 1 item.
        # When an item becomes available, yield it to client.
        try:
            count = 0
            while count != self.file_count:
                try:
                    item = self.output_queue.get(timeout=1)
                except:
                    # Queue is empty. Wait and retry.
                    time.sleep(1)
                    continue
                count += 1
                yield item
            yield 'end'
        finally:
            # Kill all child processes.
            self.pool.kill(block=True) # <- Causes segfault.
            #self.pool.kill(block=False) # <- Silently fails.
```

This **only** happens when a user makes a selection, and while processing those files, makes another selection, effectively closing the current connection and creating a new one, creating two different sets of child processes.

Why does blocking cause a segmentation fault? Why is the behavior different when blocking vs not blocking? What can I do to kill all the original processes?

Comment: unless you are using a very old (and broken) uWSGI version, every segfault should return a backtrace in the logs. Can you report it with the uWSGI configuration ?